# How does one lay out a book w/ 2 pages per 8.5x11?

Tags: page-numbering, landscape, booklet

This is my first LaTeX project, and I'm finding most of the info I need, except a concrete answer to what to use as the template for my project. It's an old family project: a booklet, printed on 8.5x11 paper, and stapled in the center that is a combination genealogy and directory. It's a format everyone is used to, so I want to stick with it.

The generated PDF SHOULD support double-sided printing, though I can work around that, if necessary, but it MUST number pages properly and MUST provide enough space between facing pages to allow for a proper binding gutter.

It has a title page, an info page (similar to Copyright page), then pages 1-n. (Let's assume 20 pages.) The Title page would have to be laid out opposite page 20, with the Title on the RIGHT. etc:

```
20     Title
"info" 19
18     1
2      17
16     3
...
8      11
10     9
```

I bashed together some Python to do a test layout - abusing a monospace font to ensure functionally-correct layout, and it gives a basic idea of what I'm after. It works, but it's ugly as hell and printing it is on the verge of black magic. It's not something I can hand to my parents and expect them to crank out a finished product.

[image: (The black lines aren't printed, of course. They're here for debugging purposes.) The Vs and Ms are there as debugging placeholder for vertical margin. Horizontally, the 7 fields are; page numbering, separator between numbering and text, text, gutters/stapling, text, space, page number.]

My trouble is that I either end up with LaTeX solutions that give me two columns of data, with a page number smack at the bottom center of the sheet, or fail to number and arrange the page numbers correctly. I'd be happy to lay out the book as a simple pdf, then use one of the includepdf solutions I've seen, if I could get them to properly number and face pages.

What's the "correct" or "accepted" template to use for this kind of work?

Comment: You should take look at the `pdfpages` package. If I understand well, each sheet of paper should contain  4 pages? For the special dimensions of the page, the `geometry` package should take care of it.

Comment: there are several packages on ctan that look promising in this respect: `booklet`, `pdfbook`, and `pdfbook2`.  (my knowledge about them is indirect only, having seen them discussed by other people; i have never used such a package.)

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this.

Step 1: set the page size to 5.5x8.5 in LaTex, and set the margins the way you want (e.g. with the `geometry` package). Create some blank pages at the end of the PDF to make the page count a multiple of 4, if necessary.

Step 2: figure out how to print the PDF in booklet format (on landscape-orientation 8.5x11 paper) and double sided. The best way to do that depends on what options your printer has. As a last resort, shuffle the pages of the PDF into "booklet" order before you print.

Trying to combine the two steps into one won't make life any simpler!